# Mongodb join multiple group of values

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

Hello I'm starting to learn mongoDB query

I have some understanding problems with aggregate

For example, I have these documents:

```
           [
            {
              totalTaxInclusive: 15,
              totalTaxExclusive: 12.5,
              payments:[{
                 method: "CB",
                 amount: 10
              },
              {
                 method: "CASH",
                 amount: 5
              }
            ],
           },
           {
              totalTaxInclusive: 40,
              totalTaxExclusive: 33.33,
              payments:[{
                 method: "CB",
                 amount: 40
              }
            ],
           },
          ]
```

and so on.

How can I make a request, who I will have a:

```
        $group: {
          _id: "$payments.method",
          amount: { $sum: "$payments.amount"},
        }
```

and a

```
$group: {
       _id: null,
       totalCount: { $sum: 1 },
       totalTaxInclusive: { $sum: "$totalTaxInclusive"},
       totalTaxExclusive: { $sum:"$totalTaxExclusive" },
     }
```

To have a result of something like:

```
{
totalCount: 2,
totalTaxInclusive: 55,
totalTaxExclusive: 45.83,
payments: [{
     method: "CASH",
     amount: 5,
    },
    {
     method: "CB",
     amount: 50,
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` by null and get the sum of required fields, construct the array of `payments`
- `$concatArrays` to concat arrays
- `$reduce` to concat nested array of `payments` to array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `payments` array
- `$group` by `method` and get the sum of `amount` and get required fields first value
- `$group` by null and construct the array of `payments` and get count fields first value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalTaxInclusive: { $sum: "$totalTaxInclusive" },
      totalTaxExclusive: { $sum: "$totalTaxExclusive" },
      totalCount: { $sum: 1 },
      payments: { $push: "$payments" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      payments: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$payments",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$payments" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$payments.method",
      amount: { $sum: "$payments.amount" },
      totalTaxInclusive: { $first: "$totalTaxInclusive" },
      totalTaxExclusive: { $first: "$totalTaxExclusive" },
      totalCount: { $first: "$totalCount" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalTaxInclusive: { $first: "$totalTaxInclusive" },
      totalTaxExclusive: { $first: "$totalTaxExclusive" },
      totalCount: { $first: "$totalCount" },
      payments: {
        $push: {
          method: "$_id",
          amount: "$amount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fKGQFdSwGMR)

Answer (score 1):

- First stage to group all documents and store their data in relevant arrays. Also count all documents in this stage.
- Second stage to sum all items in `totalTaxExclusive` and `totalTaxInclusive` arrays
- Third and forth stage to unwind `payments` because it is an array of arrays
- Forth stage to group by `payment_method` and to get total sum by each `payment_method`
- Fifth stage to output result in requested format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "totalTaxInclusive": {
        "$addToSet": "$totalTaxInclusive"
      },
      "totalTaxExclusive": {
        "$addToSet": "$totalTaxExclusive"
      },
      "payments": {
        "$addToSet": "$payments"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "totalTaxExclusive": {
        "$sum": "$totalTaxExclusive"
      },
      "totalTaxInclusive": {
        "$sum": "$totalTaxInclusive"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$payments"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$payments"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$payments.method",
      "amount": {
        "$sum": "$payments.amount"
      },
      "totalTaxInclusive": {
        "$first": "$totalTaxInclusive"
      },
      "totalTaxExclusive": {
        "$first": "$totalTaxExclusive"
      },
      "count": {
        "$first": "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "payments": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "method": "$_id",
          "amount": "$amount"
        }
      },
      "totalTaxInclusive": {
        "$first": "$totalTaxInclusive"
      },
      "totalTaxExclusive": {
        "$first": "$totalTaxExclusive"
      },
      "count": {
        "$first": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/veULWgZ6Ek2)